# Issues on length and position of tikz boxes in titlesec

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, formatting, titlesec, section-titles

I'm currently using the following code to produce a certain style of section and subsection. I'd really appreciate some help fixing the following issues: Firstly, I'd like both the red section number box and the blue subsection number box to be right aligned in the left margin (which doesn't seem to appear in showframe - why?) without the makeshift use of the \hspace command (this is the best I can manage so far, but it isn't perfect). Secondly, I'd like the box containing the titles of the section and subsection to extend as far as the end of the line of text underneath, but no further. Currently, it seems to overrun. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\llap{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]\node[draw=red!20,fill=white,inner sep=5pt,text height=1.5ex,text depth=-1ex, line width = 2pt](a){\thesection}; \hspace{0.25cm}}}
{0em}
{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]\node[fill=red!20,inner sep=6pt,text width=\linewidth-4pt,text height=1.5ex,text depth=-1ex, shading=axis,shading angle=0,left color=red!20,right color=white](a){\centering #1};}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\llap{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]\node[draw=blue!20,fill=white,inner sep=5pt,text height=1.5ex,text depth=-1ex, line width = 2pt](a){\thesubsection}; \hspace{0.275cm}}}
{0em}
{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]\node[fill=blue!20,inner sep=6pt,text width=\linewidth-4pt,text height=1.5ex,text depth=-1ex, shading=axis,shading angle=0,left color=blue!20,right color=white](a){\centering #1};}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{A subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet magna sed erat tempus, sit amet maximus est tristique.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't seem to appear in showframe"? The `showframe` option shows the area of the text body (among other things). Since the boxes containing the (sub)section numbers are outside the text body, they are also outside the relevant frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text width={\linewidth-12pt}` to get a node with appropriate width, because you need to subtract twice the `inner sep` of 6pt. Also, better not place `\hspace` inside the `\tikz` command. Note that a negative `text depth` does nothing here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\hspace*{-0.275cm}\llap{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{
    \node[draw=red!20, fill=white, inner sep=5pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0pt, line width=2pt] (a) {\thesection};
}}}
{0.275cm}
{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{
    \node[fill=red!20, inner sep=6pt, text width={\linewidth-12pt}, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0pt, shading=axis, shading angle=0, left color=red!20, right color=white] (a) {#1};
}}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\hspace*{-0.275cm}\llap{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{
    \node[draw=blue!20, fill=white, inner sep=5pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0pt, line width=2pt] (a){\thesubsection};
}}}
{0.275cm}
{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{
    \node[fill=blue!20, inner sep=6pt, text width={\linewidth-12pt}, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0pt, shading=axis, shading angle=0, left color=blue!20, right color=white] (a) {#1};
}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{A subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet magna sed erat tempus, sit amet maximus est tristique.

\end{document}
```

[image]